# "Plan B" in Russian

Tags: выражения

Plan B is a secondary plan that you could fall back on in case Plan A, so to speak, didn't pan out as expected. The notion of "switching to Plan B" exists in English {Plan B}, French {le plan B}, German {Plan B}, Italian {piano B} etc.

What is an idiomatic way to express the idea of "switching to Plan B" in Russian? Is a single alphabet commonly used instead of an adjective like "запасной"?

> **запасной** / **запасный** план

Comment: In short: yes, it's the same "План Б" thing (probably correctly expressed as `план «Б»`).

Comment: план "Б" is a copycat of English expression for translation of English phrases. Like the ниггер word was introduced into Russia to translate "dark action" American detectives of 1970-s. Outside of the scope they were created for - for Plan B it is translating foreign documents and speeches - this idiom can be rarely met. Maybe eventually it would stuck, becoming yet another "borrowed word", who knows. As of now I would stick with "запасной план". Notice however, "plan B" implies there can be plan C, plan D and so on. "Backup plan" (or would it be "fall-back plan"?) implies last chance.

Comment: @Arioch I believe this is perfectly valid to be an answer actually

Comment: @shabunc thanks. But there is no hurry. Maybe someone would come up with more comprehensive detailed info. It never is too late to learn new tricks :-D

Comment: @Arioh, I'd say it's not *that* rare these days, e.g. [club](http://fb.ru/article/149567/moskovskiy-klub-plan-b), [series](https://www.ivi.ru/watch/plan-b) etc. (sorry for spam links - I'll delete later). Aside of that I'm pretty sure the languages listed by Alone-zee also borrowed it not so long ago (just because it's not [that old](http://www.worldwidewords.org/topicalwords/tw-pla2.htm) in English itself). But in general you're right of course, it's not "genuine Russian".

Comment: @seven-phases-max that was why I wrote `Maybe eventually it would stuck, becoming yet another "borrowed word"`. Every language has a number of foreign words and idioms finally internalized. Maybe the same would be with plan B. For example i like its open-endness, making you think about existence of post-B plans. But as of now it is still alien and used only in specific situations/societies. Just like any borrowed word in its early days.

Comment: @Arioh I mean I'd rather would say it's *already* part of the language. I.e. if OP says/writes "Plan B" as "план «Б»" in Russian he's understood perfectly by *anyone* (thus it's not a sort of movie fans *slang*), though if he rather wants to sound more "native" he'd better to use "запасной" instead just like you suggest of course. But never mind, it's not that important I guess.

Comment: I'd rather wonder what was the intention behind of the question at all: i.e. if it's just about "What letter do you use?".

Comment: @seven-phases-max "understood" thing and "part of vocabulary" are still different things. Would I say водокипятитель I would be understood by anyone too.

Comment: @Arioch - for '"dark action" American detectives' I'm sure you meant *"нуар"*, and not the word that was used.

Comment: @Alexander I ain't sure noir is correct here. They were not stylish, they were more of bloody pulp fiction

Comment: @Arioch - Not sure what detective subgenre you have in mind (I'm talking about [Dashiell Hammett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashiell_Hammett)-type). I'm pretty sure neither genre was called the "N-word" in English.

Comment: Russian is my native language and I can say that "План Б" (Plan B) is perfectly understandable and used by russians). Switching to Plan B is "Переходим к плану Б"  but "запасной план" is also good. But it is "запасной", not "запасный" since "запасный" is used only with "запасный выход" (emergency exit). But in case you have "Plan C"  you must know that while "Б" is the second letter in cyrillic, the third one is "В", но "C":)

Answer (score 4):

A common phrase in Russian is **"запасной вариант"**. Here is [a chart comparing frequency of usage *"запасной вариант"* vs *"запасной план"*.](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?env=alpha&mode=main&t1=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%C2%A0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD&t2=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%C2%A0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82&start=1800&end=2010&smoothing=3&query=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%C2%A0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%2C%C2%A0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%C2%A0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82)

Examples of usage:

> - Был пущен в ход запасной вариант. / *Plan B was executed.*
> - Пошёл в ход запасной вариант. / *Plan B was executed.*
> - У него всегда есть запасной вариант. / *He always has an alternative plan.*
> - Она не рассматривала запасных вариантов. / *She did not consider alternative plans.*

Comment: good call...... the Corpora data on "запасной план" is illuminating, not that it's totally wrong but isn't yet enough settled within the language phraseology, other than that **запасной вариант** isn't a very good fit in the context of the actual worked out detailed plan, which would need a more precise term

Answer (score 1):

Оther options are **альтернативный план**, **резервный план**

And so the idea of "switching to Plan B" may be expressed as

> вводить в действие / задействовать ... план // переходить к ...
>   плану

less formally

> переключаться на ... план <sup>(*technically possible, but is somewhat unusual*)</sup>

or highly informally

> включать / запускать ... план

Comment: Never heard anyone saying "альтернативный план". Only "запасной план" or "план бэ" (though it is yet considered slangish)

Comment: neither have i, which doesn't mean it can't be used or is wrong, as long as there's no universally acceptable readily recognizable stable collocation, and it's meaning is crystal clear and Google gives loads of examples, i don't think your "**only**" is well warranted

Comment: [пример](http://www.un.org/russian/news/text_news/story.asp?newsID=27470) - *Альтернативного плана - «плана Б» - по урегулированию израильско-палестинского конфликта не существует*